# DatePickerDialog shows the incorrect date if opened and then the date changes elsewhere

Tags: android, datepicker

The code below shows a DatePickerDialog for the user to insert a date and works as expected. When the date is updated and the user closes the dialog the button which launched the DatePickerDialog is updated to show the selected date:

```
// Date Picker Section
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        Log.i(TAG, "Setting up new date picker "+timestampCalendar);
        datepicker =  new DatePickerDialog(this,
                mDateSetListener,
                timestampCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                timestampCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                timestampCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE));          
        return datepicker;
    }
    return null;
}

// updates the date we display in the Button
private void updateDateButton() {       
    timestampTextView.setText(monthName[timestampCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)]+", "+timestampCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE)+" "+timestampCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
}

// the callback received when the user "sets" the date in the dialog
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        timestampCalendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        datepicker.updateDate(timestampCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE), timestampCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), timestampCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
        updateDateButton();         
    }
};
```

But here is where i start having issues. The code below is the onClickListener for a button that adds one day to the timestampCalendar Calendar object. If i open the DatePickerDialog and close it, use the "plus1" button and then open the DatePickerDialog again it still shows the date from when i closed the DatePickerDialog  the first time.

```
plus1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
        public void onClick(View view) {    
            timestampCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            currentTimestamp = timestampCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
            updateDateButton();
        }            
    });
```

I tried to fix this by calling the updateDate() method of the DatePickerDialog in the set listener but that doesn't work either.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call this line:

```
datepicker.updateDate(timestampCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE), timestampCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), timestampCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
```

When you are using the plus1 button. This will update the date picker.

You could actually just move this line of code into updateDateButton(); to stop repetition.